# How to unzip "Zip archive data, at least v3.0 to extract" on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, compression

I downloaded some virtual machine image (IE9_Win7) from modern.ie, but I can't extract it on Ubuntu 12.04. It errors out with:

```
Archive:  IE9_Win7.zip
warning [IE9_Win7.zip]:  707116788 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
  (attempting to process anyway)
error [IE9_Win7.zip]:  start of central directory not found;
  zipfile corrupt.
  (please check that you have transferred or created the zipfile in the
  appropriate BINARY mode and that you have compiled UnZip properly)
```

I've redownloaded it several times. The archive has this file signature:

```
IE9_Win7.zip: Zip archive data, at least v3.0 to extract
```

I can unzip the IE10 archive without problems, because it's less than 4GB and has this file signature:

```
IE10_Win8.zip: Zip archive data
```

Which tool for Ubuntu 12.04 can extract the v3.0 zip?

Comment: Have you tried installing `zip` via aptitude? Via `sudo aptitude install zip`? It is version 3.0.

Comment: Yes, but the error message is from that program...